# Should the Programmers Blog Trello Board be made public?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog

The idea has been floated that we should make the [Programmers Trello board](https://trello.com/board/programmers-stack-exchange-blog/4f298fb47abe1fe662ae2b72) publicly viewable. I want to put this up to a community vote. A decision should be reached within 1 week.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the board should be made to be publicly viewable. This would allow for more transparency in the creation of the blog as well as giving other sites a template on how to run their Trello boards for their blogs. It would foster a more open atmosphere on the site and give potential authors possible ideas for what to do as far as blogging topics without having to go to the hassle of creating a profile and having the admins link it into the board.

Comment: This. I think the only reason we made it private in the first place was that it was the default option.

Comment: You realize this means someone is going to have to maintain it... (something we are not currently doing very well)

Comment: Thank you for volunteering to maintain our Trello board @Morons ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, the board should not be made publicly viewable. It would make it harder for people to post ideas that are potentially embarrassing or poorly thought out with any degree of confidence. It would potentially rob people of the will to write for the blog if they feel that their idea could not be developed in private before release.